# Running tests which match multiple groups

Tags: phpunit

I have tests of various types (unit, acceptance, etc) which I have assigned multiple labels for granularity

```
/**
 * @test
 * @group unit
 * @group controllers
 */


/**
 * @test
 * @group unit
 */


/**
 * @test
 * @group controllers
 */
```

Is it possible to run phpunit tests that *only* match two or more groups? Something like

```
--group unit|controllers
```

In this case the only test that should run would be the first test as it has both the `unit` and `controllers` group while the other tests would not run.

Using the notation

```
--group unit,controllers
```

Runs *all* tests from `unit` and then *all* (or remaining - I can't quite remember) tests from `controllers` -  In large projects this can cause long run times.

Answer (score 17):

- `--group unit,controllers` should work
- `--exclude` also exists to run all tests except those in the group(s) specified
- `@group unit|controllers` is not an allowed syntax

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, I updated my question to remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

You need to rethink usage of **@group** annotations, start with splitting to test suites. You can try to follow phpunit rules about files structure or define test suites using xml.
For ex:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
      <directory>webroot/*/Tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="integration">
      <directory>webroot/*/Tests/Integration</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="controllers">
      <directory>webroot/*/Tests/Integration/Controller</directory>
    </testsuite>

  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

**@groups** usually used to combine by business entity, for ex. to run all tests related to search functionality of your application.

more information here https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html